# jQuery plugin in Joomla 3.2 module doesn't load/work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

I'm having problems with a piece of JavaScript on my Joomla page. Please bear with me, because I'm far from an expert.

I'm using a regular (so not an actual Joomla plugin) plugin to show my portfolio. This is how it should be working: http://portfolio.heshley.nl/templates/j ... black.html

This is how it should NOT be working: http://portfolio.heshley.nl/

So, I did and tried a lot.

- I added the JavaScript library and put it way on top in the head
- I put the code in a module and changed every $ to jQuery
- I put the code in my index.php and also changed every $ to jQuery
- Used PHP in my index.php to load the external colio file index in a module
- Disabled mootools deleted double loaded scripts
- I went back to jQuery 1.10.2 as used by the colio plugin
- Changed all the links to absolute links
- I found a tons of optional solutions while googling and I tried every
  one of them. I don't remember most of them though.

I'm really lost here and the developer of the plugin didn't find a solution either. Probably because he is not really into Joomla.

Does someone know what I can do? As I mentioned above, I'm no expert, but I know the basics. So if you have a step by step solution, that would be super!

Answer (score 0):

your first link is not working, so I dont really se what's not working in the second. But: If you look in the html-source, you are loading jquery twice, once at the top (probably in the index.php-file of the jsn_yoyo_pro - template) and once further down (probably loaded by Joomla somewhere?). Try to move the includes in index.php below the

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

tag, so that Joomlas includes will come first. Then remove the includes you have that are loading the same library.

Also, I see that both jquery and mootools are loading, so I quess jquery is in no-conflict mode. This means all jquery-calls hase to be made using:

```
jQuery( ... )
```

instead of

```
$( ... )
```

(Mind the case of jQuery() ). So replace all references to $( with jQuery(

regards Jonas

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. The first link was indeed not working, but it works now.

But the thing about the jquery is that in the include head mootools is shown first, but I always learned that jquery has to be way on top for a plugin to work. I cannot change the include head as far as I know. So is it maybe better to just delete the include head and put in all the script by hand? Or does it need to be an include head to work?

As for the #(..), I found out that I had to replace all the $(..) to jQuery(..), but didn't know about the #(..). I will try that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I meant replace $(), just as you did.